# Speeding up work with huge SQL tables

Tags: php, sql, mysql

On my website I am experimenting with tables that are extremely big. One table 'items' has about 2 million records and the second one 'items_parents' about 6 millions. Surprisingly I need to join those tables. When I try for example this SQL command in MySQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `items_parent` 
JOIN items ON items_parent.id = items.id
WHERE items_parent.parent = 4706421
```

It takes about 7 seconds, which is simple too long for a website. On both tables I have double indexes (of type BTREE) on 1. ID and name - on 2. ID and parent. I dont know much about using the indexes to be honest, but its better to have two common indexes right? In the first one the name is unique, maybe that could help somehow? Or the indexes are ok? In that case what can I improve?

Thank you very much

Comment: I won't mark this as an answer and I'm entirely sure of the differences between SQL and mySQL with indexes, hopefully someone can help fill this gap for us. You'll want to make sure your column items_parent.parent is indexed, as well as your id columns on items_parent and on items. Also, if you aren't using all columns from the table, you should only bring back the columns you're needing.

Comment: Is SELECT * necessary? Try SELECTing only one column for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try putting a multi-column index on the items_parent table, making sure the parent column is listed first and then the id column listed second.

Also, if you don't need all the columns from both tables, do not do "Select *".  At a minimum here, you are getting an additional column from each table for the columns you are joining on.  Basically, the same data in 2 columns, which is a waste of time and bandwidth.

Comment: The first part wouldn't help I think, because sometimes I search according to parent, sometimes id... And I have two-column index... Second one - thanks for that, but no real improvement was made.

Comment: Tables can have multiple indexes.  I really do think this index will help a lot.

Comment: Seems you are more than right.. I found out that most of my queries arent using index, so I am reading the mysql tutorial how to use them properly, hopefully that helps.

Comment: So I figured it out! On items_parent I am using two-column index for 'parent' and 'id' and as well a one-column index for 'id'. On `items` I have primary key on 'id' and uniqeu index on 'name'. Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm curious to know... You said that originally the query was taking 7 seconds.  How long does it take now that you have better indexes?

Comment: 0.0049 seconds :) - it works great, now I am struggling a bit with searching (joining 5 tables there) but I hope indexes gonna solve that again :)

Answer (score 3):

Suggest you look at the explain plan to see if the indexes are being used.

Comment: Thanks for your help, using EXPLAIN helped me to improve the keys a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time finding a good article on "covered indices", but you can check this one out: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/

The basic idea is that if you have an index on a table on 1 or 2 columns, but you're SELECTing more data than just those columns, your query is going to have to perform another table scan just to pull the data from the table.

A covered index will include the other columns you want in the initial seek, greatly improving performance.

Comment: But Im still not sure, if thats the problem. Because eventhough if I try SELECTing only "items_parent.id, items_parent.parent" instead of "*" there is no time difference at all.